# Does the R.E.S.P.E.C.T. achievement in X3-Albion Prelude require a high Terran reputation?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

If you're not familiar with the achievement:

> R.E.S.P.E.C.T.
>
> Achieve the highest reputation with the main races

Does this require a high reputation with Terrans as well?  Is that even possible if you started on the Argon side?

If it's possible to get this achievement in X3-AP, how do you do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, you only need high rep with Argon, Boron, Split, Paranid and Teladi for the R.E.S.E.C.T. achievement. If your reputation is low with a particular race, try hanging around their border sectors shooting at their enemies (pirates, Xenon, Boron/Split, Argon/Paranid), though it will likely take a while.